# What does this authentication failure mean with OpenMediaVault on raspberry pi, and is it the reason pi is slow to connect to network

Tags: boot, boot-issues, server, case

I recently migrated my raspberry pi openmediavault server device to a new case (geekworm's naspi gemini).  I installed a [script](https://wiki.geekworm.com/X-C1_Software) by geekworm to run a pwm fan on the pi, then rebooted.  After this, the device is incredibly slow to connect to the network, thus making remote access difficult to establish.  So, I connected a monitor to the device (which I do not normally do since I usually access it remotely), I am never given the option to enter commands, instead, this is what I see:
[image]

What does this authentication failure mean?  And how can I gain the ability to enter commands this way?  And could this be related to the install of the fan script?

I can provide more details as needed.  Thank you!

Comment: Do not post text as a picture. furthermore, the picture is unreadable, so we have no clue what's going on. Please cut-and-paste the text into the question.

Comment: Apologies for the bad image, I have updated it.  How would you suggest I cut and paste the text into the question though?  This text only appears when I connect a monitor to the device, and I cannot use a browser as this is the lite os.  I suppose I could manually type the relevant text if you would prefer that…

Comment: What OS? How did you install OMV - on top of Raspberry Pi OS or OMV image? AFAIK OMV does not have user pi. What does the script DO? Changing case should not change anything.

Comment: It was Raspbian Bullseye Lite, with OMV installed on top of it.  I agree that the case shouldn’t change anything, which is why I think it may be related to the fan script somehow.  The script I mentioned controls the pwm fan on the case.  I have found this issue on the repo of someone seeming to have a similar [issue](https://github.com/geekworm-com/x-c1/issues/4)

Answer (score 0):

solution found. The pi was trying to auto-login as the pi user, but that had been deleted somehow. I fixed it by bypassing the default login using Ctrl+Alt+F2 (may be Ctrl+Alt+F1 depending on your device/keyboard). Then I logged in as my new user, and used raspi-config to change the default login behavior to the new user.